# Freecns svg icons strange bug

Tags: svg, icons

I just try to use this icon pack http://freecns.yanlu.de/ , but have strange bug:

[image: super bug]

white lines on all icons! what is it?

Comment: Sorry for that! Could you give me a version number and the date when you downloaded it?

Comment: current version, few days ago.

Comment: Ok. I'm really sorry for these bugs! Just wait a few more days for Freecns 2.0. With that all stripes should be gone!

Answer (score 0):

Done! In all svg files i found this crap:

```
<g fill="rgb(215,215,215)" id="Stripes Vertical copy">
        <g stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="1" fill="none" id="Rectangle 180 copy 5"></g>
        <path id="Rectangle 180 copy 5" d="M0,-64 L0,656 L16,656 L16,-64 L0,-64 Z M0,-64" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></path>
        <path id="Rectangle 180 copy 5 decoration" d="" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></path>
    </g>
```

that's add the white lines on the sides. Just cut this code to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Newest version is up. Should be fixed now!